# Minimal Hall Matching Violator Has Size At Most $\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, matching-theory

Source of problem: Janson, Łuczak, and Ruciński, section 4.1 (page 82, line -10).

**The question:**

Let $G = (V_1 \cup V_2, E)$ be a bipartite graph with $|V_1| = |V_2| = n$ and no perfect matching. By Hall's matching theorem, there is a set $S \subseteq V_i$ (for $i=1$ or $2$) such that $|N(S)|<|S|,$ where $N(\cdot )$ is the neighborhood in the graph $G$. Suppose $S$ is a *minimal* such 'Hall Violator'. Is it true that $|S| \leq \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$? If so, why?

**My thinking so far:**

Based on my reading about minimal Hall violators, it may be useful to fix a maximal matching in $G$; this partitions $V_1$ and $V_2$ into 'matched' sets $A_1, A_2$ of size $m < n$ and 'unmatched' sets $B_1, B_2$ of size $n-m.$

It is also notable that the condition depends on the parity of $n,$ giving a hint as to why it might be true. It is easy to show that if $S$ is a minimal Hall violator, then $|S| = |N(S)|+1.$
If we could then show that $|S| + |N(S)| \leq n,$ this translates to

$$2|S|-1 \leq n$$

$$\iff |S| \leq \frac{n+1}{2}.$$

Since $|S|$ is an integer, this translates to $|S| \leq \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, it suffices to prove $|N(S)| + |S| \leq n.$

We show something weaker--not that $|S| \leq \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$ for *any* minimal Hall violator, but rather that there *exists* a minimal Hall violator $S'$ with $|N(S')| + |S'| \leq n.$

Let $S \subset V_1$ be a minimal Hall violator.

Notice that $(|N(S)| + |S|) + (|V_2 \setminus N(S)| + |V_1 \setminus S|) = 2n.$
Thus one of these terms is $\leq n.$
But $N(V_2 \setminus N(S)) \subseteq V_1 \setminus S,$ so either $|N(S)| + |S| \leq n$ (in which case we're done!), or if that fails then $|V_2 \setminus N(S)| + |N(V_2 \setminus N(S))| \leq n$, so we can take a minimal Hall violator $S' \subseteq V_2 \setminus N(S)$, and $|S'| + |N(S')| \leq |V_2 \setminus N(S)| + |N(V_2 \setminus N(S))| \leq n.$

Comment: Note that if you interpret "minimal" to be w.r.t. cardinality, then you've proven the desired statement.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani that's interesting! I ususally use "minimum" when I mean "smallest cardinality", to disambiguate between the two meanings :)

Comment: I do so too. But in this case, I guess we do need it to mean minimum cardinality. Otherwise, consider the graph where $n = 2$ and you join both vertices of $V_1$ to a single vertex in $V_2$. Then, $S = V_1$ is a minimal (w.r.t. inclusion) Hall violator (I think).